# Kestrel/Http.sys HTTPS configuration error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https, kestrel-http-server, http.sys

I'm testing the official Asp.Net core sample https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/servers/httpsys/samples/3.x/SampleApp I'm using Visual Studio 2019 V16.4.0 (.Net 3.1)

I commented out the line `// options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:5005");` so it will use the default ports 5001 and 5000 for https and http respectively.

### Question 1: The application outputs are different when running in Visual Studio vs execute the .exe file.

Visual Studio shows it's listening on https://localhost:5001.

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener[0]
      Start
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener[0]
      Listening on prefix: https://localhost:5001/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener[0]
      Listening on prefix: http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\AspNetCore.Docs-master\AspNetCore.Docs-master\aspnetcore\fundamentals\servers\httpsys\samples\3.x\SampleApp
```

However, when running the exe file, it doesn't listen to https://localhost:5001

```
PS C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\AspNetCore.Docs-master\AspNetCore.Docs-master\aspnetcore\fundamentals\servers\httpsys\samples\3.x\SampleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1> .\HttpSysSample.exe
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener[0]
      Start
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener[0]
      Listening on prefix: http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\AspNetCore.Docs-master\AspNetCore.Docs-master\aspnetcore\fundamentals\servers\httpsys\samples\3.x\SampleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1
```

### Question 2: web page https://localhost:5001/ gets error? (when running in Visual Studio)

The web page returns the following message in Chrome.

> This site can’t be reached
>
> The connection was reset.

In Edge, it displays

> Can’t connect securely to this page
>
> This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner.

**Update:**
Running `.\HttpSysSample.exe --urls https://*:5005` enables the https with the command line execution. However, it will get the same error above.

Comment: "The settings in UrlPrefixes override UseUrls/urls/ASPNETCORE_URLS settings. Therefore, an advantage of UseUrls, urls, and the ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable is that it's easier to switch between Kestrel and HTTP.sys."

This likely means that when you run it from powershell its missing that environmental variable and like you put in your update you need to pass it in as argument.

Question 2 is definitely about https - i think you need to call app.usehttpsredirection() - that may help.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Also make sure the dev cert is installed and trusted. (sme help page as above)

Comment: I've recreated and trusted dev cert. `dotnet dev_certs https --trust` but no luck. I tried  `.\HttpSysSample.exe --urls https://*:5005` and got the same error.

Comment: Should I create my own certificate and let the problem use it instead of the dev cert?

Comment: Visual Studio uses settings from launchSettings.json, so differences can be  expected, https://www.talkingdotnet.com/launchsetting-json-in-aspnet-5/ HTTPS errors are also common, as you need valid HTTP API mappings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background